# Getting a throwOnFind: false response from Ardent in Laravel

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, laravel, ardent

I'm trying to perform an .ajax get to populate a table using Knockout/Jquery in Laravel 4. I use Ardent and it keeps responding with the following json response.

```
{"throwOnFind":false}
```

**Controller**:

```
    public function getData()
{
    $roles = Role::select(array('roles.id',  'roles.name', 'roles.id as users', 'roles.created_at'));
    return Response::json($roles, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function Role(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.users = ko.observable(data.users);
    this.created_at = ko.observable(data.created_at);
}
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.roles = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{ URL::to('admin/roles/data') }}",
        complete: function(allData) {
            var mappedRoles = $.map(allData, function(item) {
                return new Role(item);
            });
        }
    }, "json");

    self.roles(mappedRoles);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I don't really know where to go from here. I think the problem may be in Ardent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `select` method because the  `Role::select(...)` only returns a query object ([Builder](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent/blob/master/src/LaravelBook/Ardent/Builder.php)) and not the result itself.

So need to use the other methods like `get` to execute the query and get the actual result.

So you need to write something liek:

```
$query = Role::select(array('roles.id',  ... , 'roles.created_at'));
$roles = $query->get();
return Response::json($roles, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

Comment: So simple. Also I had to go with the mapping plugin for Knockout to get this displayed.